# Disable IQKeyboardManager in ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, iqkeyboardmanager

To disable IQKeyboardManager in a viewcontroller in Swift, you apparently need to get a reference to the instance and then disable it. However, I cannot figure out a way to reference it. I originally import the library in the appDelegate which is written in Objective-C as

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
```

Give me the error:

> No Such Module IQKeyboardManagerSwift

If I merely try to put the lines below in viewDid Load:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = false
IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = false
```

Then I get error

> IQKeyboardManager not found.

How do you disable IQKeyboardManager for a specific view controller in Swift?

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/wiki/Manual-Management#enabledisable-distance-handling-between-different-viewcontrollers) mentions a possible solution: (the syntax may be a bit different depending on the version of the framework you're using)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
        IQKeyboardManager.shared().enabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(EnabledViewController.self)
        IQKeyboardManager.shared().disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(DisabledViewController.self)
        return true
    }
```

if you need the toolbar disabled/enabled as well

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared().enabledToolbarClasses.append(ToolbarEnabledViewController.self)
IQKeyboardManager.shared().disabledToolbarClasses.append(ToolbarDisabledViewController.self)
```